# Twisted MySQL adbapi return dictionary

Tags: python, twisted

Is there any way to return dictionary result from adbapi query to MySQL?

```
[name: 'Bob', phone_number: '9123 4567']
```

Default returns tuple.

```
['Bob', '9123 4567']
```

For simple Python & MySQL we can use **MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor**. But how to use it with twisted adbapi

---

**UPD:** I solved it but I think there should be better way. My solution: just override *_runInteraction* method of *adbapi.ConnectionPool* class.

```
class MyAdbapiConnectionPool(adbapi.ConnectionPool):
def _runInteraction(self, interaction, *args, **kw):
    conn = self.connectionFactory(self)
    trans = self.transactionFactory(self, conn)
    try:
        result = interaction(trans, *args, **kw)
        if(result and isinstance(result[0], (list, tuple))):
            colnames = [c[0] for c in trans._cursor.description]
            result = [dict(zip(colnames, item)) for item in result]         
        trans.close()
        conn.commit()
        return result
    except:
        excType, excValue, excTraceback = sys.exc_info()
        try:
            conn.rollback()
        except:
            log.err(None, 'Rollback failed')
        raise excType, excValue, excTraceback
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can direct MySQLdb to use `DictCursor` by passing it as the value for the `cursorclass` argument to the `connect` function.  `ConnectionPool` allows you to pass arbitrary arguments through to the connect method:

```
import MySQLdb
pool = ConnectionPool("MySQLdb", ..., cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
...
```

When you run a query, you'll get a `dict` back instead of a tuple, eg `runQuery("SELECT 1")` produces a result of `({'1': 1L},)`

Comment: Nowadays we need to do import MySQLdb.cursors for execution this code.